# What is the revenue split between me and Google in the Play store?

Tags: google-play

I want to sell an app on the Google Chrome store for $0.50. How much of this will I pocket after Google's cut?

Answer (score 3):

what i got from here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en , 0.50 * 70% = 0.35 $ or 35 cents